# Why don't all my Kafka commits actually commit? (0.9.0.1)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an application that pre-loads 1 million strings to a topic having 4 partitions, so 250K ea.

The application then fires up 2 readers with manually assigned partitions:

```
Reader 1 -> Partition 0 & 1
Reader 2 -> Partition 2 & 3
```

I buzz through and read from the partitions and do an consumer.commitAsync on each ConsumerRecord I read (no batching of commits at this point, intentionally, until I understand behavior).

I put a per-topic counter inside the commit async callback to measure how many times it was called, and the total comes to 1 million.

After the application settles down and stops, I use the Kafka CLI tools to look at my offsets I get something like:

```
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
group1          lowercaseStrings               0   233788          250000          16212           none
group1          lowercaseStrings               1   249999          250000          1               none
group1          lowercaseStrings               2   249999          250000          1               none
group1          lowercaseStrings               3   233788          250000          16212           none
```

Note that the Lag of 1 in two of these is coincidental--I sometimes get different numbers.

I watch the async commit callback function for any passed-in exceptions, and there are none.  According to my code I've called commitAsync 1 million times as expected.

Why do I still have this kind of lag?  What might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka fetches messages in batches. When you call next() in your message Stream, two things can happen :
 - Either there's no data locally, and your consumer will internally call poll(), which will update its offset status
 - Either there's some, and you'll advance in your local batch.

When you call commitAsync(), you commit the offsets you got at your last poll() call, not the one you're currently effectively at by iterating internally.

You can control this behaviour by reducing the size of the batches you accept (setting batch.size in your configuration), down to 0 if you really want to poll() for every message. I expect that with this config down to 0, you'll reach 0 lag everywhere (beware that for scalable usage, this will destroy your throughput).